# Expo crash after wifi recovery from airplane

Tags: android, react-native, android-wifi, expo

im using expo in a Android tablet (Android 7.0)

Im testing the reconnection of my app so i puted it on Airplane mode, then i turned off, and then when the app has wifi again.. Crashed it, and restart it self.

The crazy thing here is that when i do the same over 4g network, it didn't crash.

So, maybe is an issue of my device, but im not able to get any crash logs, there is any way to get some information that help me know what is happend here?

i try with: adb logcat *:W | grep exp
but nothing useless there.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try `npm install --save react-native-scripts@1.13.1` and tell me if this fix it!

Comment: I tried but it didn't work, its seems like its a react-native problem, because all apps crashes, even the Bloomberg app. Thanks to take the time to answer. Appreciate it

Comment: @MatCas did you managed to resolve this issue?

Comment: @DiyorbekSadullayev it's most likely your code is the problem, check how you handle the change of connections.